# Java Dropbox HttpServletRequest ( java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.)

Tags: java, servlets

in my java SWING app, the user can transfer files to his DropBox space, I have successfully implemented the library and I'm trying to get the user's access token without having to copy and paste it into my app.
According to the [documentation](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.0.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxWebAuth.html), I have to use HttpServletRequest to get what I want, but I get an exception, as written in the title.

```
public class LoginServlet implements HttpServletRequest {

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    // read form fields
    String token = request.getParameter("data-token");
 
 
    // get response writer
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

    // build HTML code
    String htmlRespone = "<html>";
    htmlRespone += "<h2>token: " + token + "<br/>";
    htmlRespone += "</html>";

    // return response
    writer.println(htmlRespone);

    response.sendRedirect(Main.redirectUri);
    

}
 @Override
public HttpSession getSession(boolean bln) {      
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public HttpSession getSession() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

and in Main class

```
 LoginServlet request = new LoginServlet();
       
        // Fetch the session to verify our CSRF token
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        String sessionKey = "dropbox-auth-csrf-token";
        DbxSessionStore csrfTokenStore = new DbxStandardSessionStore(session, sessionKey);

        DbxRequestConfig config = new DbxRequestConfig("User"); //Client name can be whatever you like
        DbxAppInfo appInfo = new DbxAppInfo(App key, App secret);
        DbxWebAuth webAuth = new DbxWebAuth(config, appInfo);
        DbxWebAuth.Request authRequest = DbxWebAuth.newRequestBuilder()
                .withRedirectUri(redirectUri, csrfTokenStore)
                .build();

        String url = webAuth.authorize(authRequest);

        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URL(url).toURI());

        DbxAuthFinish authFinish;
        try {
            authFinish = webAuth.finishFromRedirect(redirectUri, csrfTokenStore, request.getParameterMap());
        } catch (DbxWebAuth.BadRequestException ex) {
            //log("On /dropbox-auth-finish: Bad request: " + ex.getMessage());
            //response.sendError(400);
            return;
        } catch (DbxWebAuth.BadStateException ex) {
            // Send them back to the start of the auth flow.
            //response.sendRedirect(redirectUri);
            return;
        } catch (DbxWebAuth.CsrfException ex) {
            //log("On /dropbox-auth-finish: CSRF mismatch: " + ex.getMessage());
            //response.sendError(403, "Forbidden.");
            return;
        } catch (DbxWebAuth.NotApprovedException ex) {
            // When Dropbox asked "Do you want to allow this app to access your
            // Dropbox account?", the user clicked "No".

            return;
        } catch (DbxWebAuth.ProviderException ex) {
            //log("On /dropbox-auth-finish: Auth failed: " + ex.getMessage());
            //response.sendError(503, "Error communicating with Dropbox.");
            return;
        } catch (DbxException ex) {
            //log("On /dropbox-auth-finish: Error getting token: " + ex.getMessage());
            //response.sendError(503, "Error communicating with Dropbox.");
            return;
        }
        String accessToken = authFinish.getAccessToken();

        // Save the access token somewhere (probably in your database) so you
        // don't need to send the user through the authorization process again.
        // Now use the access token to make Dropbox API calls.
        DbxClientV2 client = new DbxClientV2(config, accessToken);
        //...
```

full stack

```
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:873)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
    at cloud.LoginServlet.getSession(LoginServlet.java:404)
    at cloud_new.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

the row `at cloud_new.Main.main(Main.java:103)`
is this  `HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);`

Comment: Can you include the full exception stack ?

Comment: The HttpServletRequest is a request from Dropbox to a Servlet that your application needs to provide. You seem to be extending HttpServletRequest but implementing a Servlet. The exception you see is being thrown from your own code.

Comment: So you restarted the bounty? You still don't understand that what you're trying to do is impossible?

Comment: @Olivier so this (https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.0.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxWebAuth.html)
 is fake for you????I've seen Java applications around that do this !!

Comment: That documentation is about web apps, not Swing apps (I had already said it in a previous comment that you deleted, BTW).

Comment: The only way you could do what you want is by embedding a web server in your app, and redirect Dropbox to it.

Comment: You could use [NanoHTTPD](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd) to embed a web server in your app. Then use `"http://localhost:8080/"` for the redirectUri.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @JRichardsz no, as already mentioned, my goal is to get the dropbox access token, without having it manually copied and pasted by the user.

Comment: #1 Are you familiar with oauth2? #2 If you want an access_token, user will need to perform a web dropbox login somehow. Since your app is a desktop app, are you open to hear how to do that? #3 Does your application need to generate the token without a human user login?

Comment: my desktop app uses the Dropbox library to upload and download files. At the first start the user must give consent, and log in to dropbox, which generates an access-token (all via browser) and then has to copy the access-token and paste it in my app .... I want to avoid that the user copies and pastes the string.

Comment: The Dropbox API only supports the "token" and "code" OAuth 2 flows, both of which require user interaction in the browser. This login web page should not be displayed in a web-view, web browser is required without alternatives. This challenge was solved in some shell client of platforms like heroku and google cloud. Are you open to hear How these world class services do that?

Comment: [this ](https://safeincloud.ladesk.com/178979-Download) desktop app does it in in C#, how is it possible that in Java SWING it is not possible?

Comment: Windows and c# are not a good examples. Also this link is related to microsoft cloud security. You are using dropbox, so you are limited to use only dropbox platform restrictions. As a summary, you need a browser user consent, and dropbox and others platforms does not allow browser emulations (java), you need a real browser. Let me know if you are interested in how heroku and gcp achieve this

Comment: friend, i understand what you say, i want to do exactly what that app does in the link i wrote. That is, obtain the access token without having it pasted to the user.

Comment: that's what i'm telling you. Do you think google and heroku force their users to do that? Is an elegant way to do that whitout copy paste tokens

Answer (score 0):

#### Note

This is not a solution for the main java question relate to some http error.

This is a proposed approach based or inspired in how heroku auth and google container registry auth works.

Also dropbox and other platforms does not offer a kind of special admin api_key to consume the final user resources. Due to that a web login in a real browser is required and this cannot be easily replaced or emulated with web_views or internal browsers in android or ios. [Source](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-API-Support-Feedback/Authorisation-flow-for-a-Python-client-console-app/m-p/350569/highlight/true#M20104)

#### Basic idea

Develop a web application which exposes two functionalities: receive the redirect from dropbox authorization platform and a rest endpoint to query if user is authenticated.

#### Assumptions

- web called my-oauth2-helper.com

#### Flow

- user starts the desktop application.
- desktop application queries to `my-oauth2-helper.com/validate/auth` sending user email.
- `my-oauth2-helper.com/validate/auth` returns a field which indicate that user does not have a valid authentication and other field with the dropbox login url.
- dropbox login url which has the classic oauth2 fields previously configured in dropbox developer console: client_id, `redirect_uri`, etc.
- desktop application uses this login url to open a browser tab.
- User is prompted with a valid dropbox web login, enter its credentials and accept the [consent](https://aem.dropbox.com/cms/content/dam/dropbox/www/en-us/landing-pages/developers/oauth-guide/side-by-side.png) page.
- Dropbox following the oauth2 protocol, redirects the user to a
  `my-oauth2-helper.com/redirect` which is the classic field called `redirect_uri`
- `my-oauth2-helper.com/redirect` receive the auth_code and exchange it for a valid `access_token` for this user and store it  in a kind of database. After that could shows a message like: "Now, you can close this page and returns to the desktop application"
- Since user was prompted with dropbox web login, the desktop application started to queries at regular intervals if user has a valid authentication to the endpoint `my-oauth2-helper.com/token` sending the email as request parameter
- After valid `access_token` generation , the `my-oauth2-helper.com/token` endpoint returns a valid access_token for this user.
- This `access_token` is ready to use in order to consume any dropbox api feature, which user accepted in consent page.